# fopen(): SSL: The operation completed successfully

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, fopen

```
$stream = stream_context_create( $params );
$fp = fopen( 'https://'.$host.$path, 'rb', false, $stream );
if(!$fp) {
  throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured can't open" );
}
$response = stream_get_contents ( $fp );
```

I'm accessing amazon product advertising API using fopen. Most of the time the code works fine but sometimes it throws an error or warning I can't really tell because It just says the operation completed successfully.

**fopen(): SSL: The operation completed successfully**

and stops code execution

Comment: `try catch` and get the error?

Comment: oh right thank you

Comment: @Cid would you please put that in the answer section?